# Replace string between “variabletext[” and “]” with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, replace

I'm trying to build an html form that generates structured JSON code from the input values. This form uses repeat fields.
I have to modify name attributes in cloned fields.

In Javascript I have a string 'menu-item[0][offers][0][price]'.
I would like to replace 'menu-item[0]' with 'menu-item[1]', as in example at http://regexr.com/3gpnt
I'm using RegExp, but is not required.

This is my experiment, but it doesn't work.

```
var string = 'menu-item[0][offers][price]';
var itemName = 'menu-item';
var regExp = new RegExp(itemName + '\[(.*?)\]', "");
var newString = string.replace(regExp, itemName + '[1]');
console.log(newString);
alert(newString);
```

Returns 'menu-item[0][offers][price]'.

Test on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lorenzodetomasi/dmnd7f9L/

Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/54ovu27y/1/

Comment: var str = ''menu-item[0][offers][price]';
str.replace('menu-item[0]', 'menu-item[1]');

look at link! how is work replace method for string https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) seems to do what you're after (but unfortunately pulls jquery in as a dependency)